# Get the corresponding value from indexes

Tags: python, numpy

I have a target columns [Value_0, ... Value_n] and an index column [idx_0, ... idx_k] I would like to get the corresponding colums [Value_{idx_0}, ... Value_{idx_k}]
BUT I have these three difficulties.

1. The index column are in type float
2. The index column can have NaN Values
3. If the index column has NaN value, I would like that the Output column return a NaN value at the same place.

How can I do that efficiently (in a numpy way, without looping) ?

I suspect that writting a code like
 `Value[Idx[~np.isnan(Idx)].astype(int)]`
will not allow me the third condition.

Only writting `Value[Idx.astype(int)]` has an issue since python is not able to convert NaN into int. And just writting `Value[Idx]` will not work since the type of Idx is float...

I am absolutelly not working on Pandas (company choice...) and convert a thing as pandas type can take me lot of time. (Hyper custom implementation...)
So just using numpy, and no loop (lot of data, loop will take too many time)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR one-line version: Given an array of values `v` and an array of indices `i` per your description, your result is `np.where(np.isnan(i), np.nan, v[np.where(np.isnan(i), 0, i.astype(int))])`

Let's look at a simple example step by step:

```
#values
v = np.array([0, 10, 20])
#indices, including NaN
i = np.array([2., np.nan, 1.])
```

The intended output would be `[20, NaN, 10]`. Like you said, we can't index with `float`, so let's make an integer index array `i1`:

```
i1 = i.astype(int) # [2, -9223372036854775808, 1]
```

The NaN was turned into some huge negative integer that is not a valid index to our tiny array. So trying advance indexing `v[i1]` would raise an `IndexError`.

So let's FIX those integers to get rid of the IndexError. 0 is always a valid index, so let's make a `i2` that is equal to `i1` except where `i` has NaN:

```
i2 = np.where(np.isnan(i), 0, i1) # [2, 0, 1]
```

Now let's try indexing and store it as `r0`:

```
r0 = v[i2] # [20,  0, 10]
```

So close, but it does not have NaN where `i` has NaN. Let's just replace the value like we did with the indices earlier:

```
result = np.where(np.isnan(i), np.nan, r0) # [20., nan, 10.]
```

NaN is a `float` value, so our original integer `v` values were coerced to `float` as well. Not much you can do about this, NumPy arrays can only hold one numerical type.

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong, but ```np.where(np.isnan(i), 0, i.astype(int))``` can be replace by ```i.fillna(0)```.
Thanks a lot for this solution ! :)

Comment: NumPy arrays do not have a `fillna` method.
Also if this works for you, go ahead and hit the check mark to resolve the post.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the data that I have is not fully numpy contrary to what my collaborator said. (And also there are not exactly NaN values since these Nan values can be converted to int...)